# Creating dictionary from csv, need key to be the zipcode

Tags: python

I need to be able to search through the dictionary by zipcode but I keep getting a `TypeError: sliced indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`.
I'm not sure how to integrate the `__index__` method.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import csv
import re

dicts = []

def getzip():
    try:
        f = open("zips.csv")
        csvParser = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csvParser:
            dicts['zip code':row[0]] = {'latitude': row[2], 'longitude': row[3]}
            print dicts
    except ValueError:
        pass
getzip()
```

If I swap in `dicts = {'zip code': row[1],'latitude': row[2], 'longitude': row[3]}`
everything works but it prints `Latitude:xxxxx zipcode:xxxxx longitude:xxxxx` and I need it to be structured by zipcode.

Comment: There are a lot of statements in your `try` block. It's a good idea to keep the `try` block as as small as possible, so that you don't accidentally ignore exceptions that you don't expect.

Comment: What do you intend to store in "dicts", a list, or a dictionary from zip code to coordinates?

Comment: zipcodes with their respective coordinates, and then i need to write a code to filter through zipcodes of within 50 miles of the user inputted zipcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically a syntax error. What are you trying to do with `dicts['zip code':row[0]]`?

Python thinks you're using the slice operator, like you would to get a middle portion of a list like `some_list[2:5]` (which returns items from index 2 through index 4 of `some_list`). `'zip code'` doesn't work as a slice index, since it's not a number.

I think you want to do:

```
dicts = {}
```

By declaring `dicts` with `{}` it's a dictionary, so you can use your zip codes as keys.

Then:

```
     dicts[row[0]] = {'latitude': row[2], 'longitude': row[3]}
```

or perhaps

```
     zip_code = row[0]
     dicts[zip_code] = {'zip code': zip_code, 'latitude': row[2], 'longitude': row[3]}
```

You could then access the information for zip code 91010 with `dicts['91010']`:

```
>>> print dicts['91010']['latitude']
'-34.12N'
```

Comment: I updated my answer to more clearly explain why to use `dicts = {}`

Comment: zipcode= row[0].strip()
            dicts[zipcode] = {'latitude': row[2].replace('"', '').strip(), 'longitude': row[3].replace('"', '').strip()}
            print dicts['10306']['latitude']

Comment: thats my current code, but it gives me keyword error: '10306'

Comment: @Matthew I think you're trying to print `dicts['10306']` before the line from your CSV with the 10306 zip code is parsed.

Comment: @Matthew I put my full test code on pastebin. Try it. http://pastebin.com/9D1TiUAw

Answer (score 1):

This defines a list which is accessed by an index:

```
dicts = []
dicts[0] = 'something'
```

This will define a dictionary which is accessed by keys:

```
dicts = {} # curly braces
dicts['key'] = 'value'
```

And my guess is, that a `{}` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line `dicts[zip code:row[0]]`. You are trying to use a list as if it were a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
{'zip code': xxx, 'latitude': xxx, 'longitude': xxx }
```

Do this:

```
{'xxx' : { 'latitude': xxx, 'longitude': xxx } } 
 #zipcode
```